# C++ Template in constructor

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17

I have this weird issue where my c++ codes failed to build; it was able to build before but i am puzzled why i am facing this issue now;

> error: C2065: 'T': undeclared identifier

at this line in the class constructor.

`Diagnostic(int* pointer, std::function<QVariant(int*)> fn = [](int* pointer){return QVariant::fromValue(std::remove_pointer_t<T>(pointer)) ;})`

```cpp
template<typename T>
class Diagnostic : QObject
{
    using T3 = std::remove_pointer_t<T>;
public:

    Diagnostic(int* pointer, std::function<QVariant(int*)> fn = [](int* pointer){return QVariant::fromValue(std::remove_pointer_t<T>(pointer));} )
    {
    }

};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int * test = new int;
    *test=5;
    Diagnostic<int*> dg(test);
    delete test;
}
```

However if the code below is ok

```cpp
template<typename T>
class Diagnostic : QObject
{
    using T3 = std::remove_pointer_t<T>;
public:

    Diagnostic(int* pointer)
    {
        std::function<QVariant(int*)> fn = [](int* pointer){return QVariant::fromValue(std::remove_pointer_t<T>(pointer)) ;};
    }

};
```

But the second one is not what i want, as i need to pass the function
std::function<QVariant(int*)> fn into a base class during class instantiation.
Any help is appreciated. I don't know why there is such error when previously i can build the codes.

Comment: Please post the complete error message. By filling the gaps this is how far I could get: https://godbolt.org/z/sMafG4bo9. `std::remove_ptr` is not to remove pointerness from a value, but it is to remove the pointer from a type. You cannot cast a `int*` to `int` like that. Dereference operator is `*`

Comment: if `fromValue` really a static method? I have doubts whether the "ok" code is actually ok

Comment: Which is the purpose of `std::remove_pointer_t<T>(pointer)`? casting `int*` into `int`?

Comment: Compile fine [here](https://godbolt.org/z/bqvKe36hr) (with dummy Qt objects).

Comment: @Jarod42 OP wants `Diagnostic<int*>` and I think your `fromValue` is called with a `int*` while OP wants to call with `int`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number: `Diagnostic<int*>` [works](https://godbolt.org/z/d9WYh3hYf) too (I have to target 32bits because of the suspicious cast).

Comment: anyhow, `'T': undeclared identifier` does not make much sense, we need to see the complete error message

Comment: @Jarod42 but does not compile [in MS VC++](https://godbolt.org/z/jaT7fE9M9).
Error message [error: C2065:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/compiler-error-c2065?view=msvc-160) in the original post points to MSVC++.

Comment: So msvc's bug in C++17 mode :-/

Comment: @Jarod42 looks like this

Comment: Hi, thanks for all the comments; yes, i have built this codes before using VC++2019, but with a slightly older compiler, but still c++17,  and all this came crumbled down after i upgraded my VS2019 version, and i can't get it back to work now. I downgrade my compiler, same. I think some settings changed, which i couldn't figured out what are those.

Comment: Anyone managed to build it again with VC++, what settings used? I can build the codes stated here previously https://godbolt.org/z/jaT7fE9M9 easily with x86-64 gcc 11.1 for example. As said i build with MSVC before, but i want to get it work in windows again.

Comment: i can change the codes, but these are existing codes which i am reluctant to change unless it is a bug; it works on both linux and windows before, it work and build fine with both linux and windows; i want to be able to build again with Windows, just that something changed in the compiler upgrade and settings which i am not able to get back now... anyone managed to build with MVC++ c++17 or above?

Comment: i checked and msvc before 19.28(16.9) seems to build, but i can't find anywhere to change my compiler version from VS 2019 IDE?? I have downloaded the older version of compiler now. There is only platform toolset, but that is related to VS2019 or VS2017, not selecting compiler version.

Comment: Reported the bug to Microsoft
https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/Regression---1928169-has-a-bug-with/1472255

Comment: @mce16 There is no option to select a C++ compiler version in Visual Studio.

Comment: @Spock77 you are right,, i tried searching everywhere and there is nowhere to set the compiler choice. Ironically, below link created a few years back by someone from Microsoft? seems to provide guidance in choosing the compiler, again i don't know if anyone is able to do what he is doing. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/use-any-c-compiler-with-visual-studio/

Comment: i don't understand why this feature is removed from VStudio? or Perhaps another bug in MSVC?? To be sure, i can install a lower version build tool into MSVC, which basically provides a different compiler version, however, MSCV will always go back to its original compiler.

Comment: @mce16 You can build via MS build tools from command line, setting proper dev environment. Build Tools are easier to reinstall, than VS, and they contain exactly the same set of compiler files as in the folder shipped with Visaul Studio. And there never was such option in VS as to select a compiler.

Comment: MS answered: you need /Zc:lambda to compile the original code https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/Regression---1928169-has-a-bug-with/1472255

Answer (score 1):

If remove not relevant details, the error is caused by the code like this (MS VC++):

```
template<typename T>
Diagnostic(int* pointer, std::function<int(int)> = [](int n) {
        int m = std::remove_pointer_t<T>();
        return m;
    });
// error C2065: 'T': undeclared identifier
```

Compiler does not recognize class template parameter T as a type inside lambda body, which is declared as the default parameter. You can bypass it by declaring a template lambda beforehand:

```
template<typename U>
auto lam = [](int n) -> int {
    auto v = U(); // use of U template parameter
    return n;
};

template<typename T>
class Diagnostic {
public:
    Diagnostic(int* pointer, std::function<int(int)> = lam<T>); // T from the class
```

Using class template type T in the default parameter itself is OK.

However, if the goal is to pass the function to a base class, you can write:

```
class QObject {
public:
    QObject(std::function<int(int)>) {}
};

template<typename T>
class Diagnostic : public QObject {
public:
    Diagnostic(int* pointer) : QObject([](int n) {
            int m = std::remove_pointer_t<T>();
            return m;
        }
    )
```

Try to figure out what is happening, simplifying the expressions and thus reducing complexity.

Comment: To be clear, using the template parameter there is legitimate; MSVC is in error if it rejects it.

Comment: Bug reported to Microsoft
https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/Regression---1928169-has-a-bug-with/1472255

Comment: MS answered: you need /Zc:lambda to compile the original code https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/Regression---1928169-has-a-bug-with/1472255

Comment: I noted the latest MSVC compiler has fixed this, from compiler explorer.

Comment: Yes, they fixed the bug - good then. 
https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/Regression---1928169-has-a-bug-with/1472255